# PHP fetching data using int column

Tags: php, mysql

Below code
IS NOT working

```
$ID=2;
mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db(productlist) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query='SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =$ID' ;
$result=mysql_query($query);
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $array['Size'];
mysql_close();
```

but when i use 2 instead of $ID it is working

```
   //$ID=2;
    mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db(productlist) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query='SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =2' ;
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $array['Size'];
    mysql_close();
```

first please tell me how to typecast integer of PHP to int of database?
can any one help me what is the problem in 1st case.. ?? ProductID column is INT in database

Comment: Before you do `$query =` what happens when you do `echo $ID`?

Comment: You could try `$query="SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID ='$ID'";`

Comment: Note the the `mysql_` lib is outdated and dangerous, use PDO instead. Bobby tables will the grateful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work and see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query='SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =$ID' ;
```

Should be:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =$ID" ;
```

Since the '-string don't parse variables.

Comment: Actually it "should be" `'SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums WHERE ProductID = '.$ID` - concatenation is a lot easier than interpolation.

Comment: Yes, but it turns ugly when there is many variables

Comment: yea yea kolink thank you .. sorry i included $ID inside thank u so much .. kolink

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP variables are not interpolated inside single quotes

```
$query='SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =$ID' ;  // $ID Should be inside double quotes or outside all


$query="SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =".$ID ;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use SQL query in 2 options

```
$query="SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =$ID";
       ^                                                 ^
```

or

```
$query="SELECT * FROM HolisticSerums where ProductID =". $ID;
```